# Search for special case strings with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm searching for String in all the modules of my project with: `"(.*?)"`

However it returns all the strings included those in annotations for example. In what way I can search for a string specific to assigned string values, i.e. through `method.call(param1, param2, "param3");` only.

Comment: Why do you need to search for all strings? Maybe it will be easier to create a custom inspection?

Answer (score 3):

Use [structural search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) for that:

1. Open structural search window
2. Insert  `"$String$"` into Search Template
3. Click Find
4. Check the results in "Find" tool window
   [image]

If you want too find string literals in calls of an exact method:

1. Add its name to the template, so search template will look like `method.call($String$)`
2. Configure filter for `$String$` variable. Regex could be used here, e.g. `.*".*`
   [image]

Comment: Nice. Learned something new. Thanks!

Comment: This search `"$String$"` still finds the strings in Java annotations